# What is a sigma complex?

Tags: organic-chemistry, resonance

According to Wikipedia, "sigma complex" refers to an arenium ion.

The suffix "-ium" denotes a positively charged ion.

So, it is correct to call the resonance structures in the below picture depictions of a sigma complex? It's distinctly anionic rather than cationic.

[image]

Answer (score 13):

Yes, it's anionic sigma complex, more precisely [Meisenheimer complex](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Meisenheimer_complex). They are much more stable then [arenium ions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arenium_ion) (Wheland intermediates) and can be isolated much [more easily](http://pubs.acs.org/doi/abs/10.1021/cr00050a004).

There was actually synthesized a sigma complex which is a zwitterionic combination of *both* Meisenheimer *and* Wheland complexes, which shows how well they can be stabilised:

[image: synthesis]

(picture created by Wikipedia [User:V8rik](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User:V8rik))

The term "sigma complex" has also other meanings. Organometallic compounds with sigma bonds connecting with aromatic rings are called [like](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyclopentadienyl_complex#.CF.83-complexes) [that](http://chemwiki.ucdavis.edu/Inorganic_Chemistry/Organometallic_Chemistry/Ligands/%CF%83_Complexes), too. There are also sigma [complexes](http://pubs.acs.org/doi/abs/10.1021/ja00472a026) of cyclobutadiene with aluminium chloride.

Generally, molecules are called sigma complexes to stress the difference between them and [pi complexes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pi_interaction) which can also be created from cyclic annulenes. First ones are bonded using sigma bonds, the other ones use pre-existing pi orbitals.